# How do I center the borders

Tags: html, css

I'm just learning HTML and CSS. I'm trying to design a flex site, but I couldn't solve the problem with borders. So, how can I center the borders? Thank you.

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu a {
  color: green;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 6px;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuBar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/garanti_logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bireysel</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kobi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ticari / Kurumsal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I have a problem and cant fix it` is very broad and vague. You need to be way more specific. what is the excat problem? what isnt workign as itnended? what have you tried so far. What is th intended behavior and layout? Using flex as a container and then inline-block as child elements is btw pretty senseless. Then you dont need a contaienr with flex in the first palce if no child element actually can flex.

Comment: I am using this platform for the first time, I will consider what you say. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `.menu ul li { display:` to `inline-flex;`

```css
.menu {
width: 100%;
height: 65px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: skyblue;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu ul li {
display: inline-flex;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu a {
color: green;
font-size: 18px;
border: 2px solid green;
border-radius: 6px;
clear: both;
padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuBar">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/garanti_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bireysel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kobi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ticari / Kurumsal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ul's have default margin and padding that you need to clear.

```css
.menu {
width: 100%;
height: 65px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
align-items:center;
background-color: skyblue;
margin-top: 20px;
}

ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;}

.menu ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}

.menu a {
color: green;
font-size: 18px;
border: 2px solid green;
border-radius: 6px;
clear: both;
padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuBar">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/garanti_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bireysel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kobi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ticari / Kurumsal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly you are trying to center the `div` with `class="menu"`

```
.menu {
width: 100%;
height: 65px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: skyblue;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I had to center the borders inside the div. I solved the problem, thank you